# Beamer poster template header logo problem

Tags: beamer, titles, posters

I am using this beamer poster template from overleaf :
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/quadratic-function/hjbvztxdrvwf#.WC_FPNyuMgc

Unfortunately in the style file there is no provision for institute logo in the header (either left corner or right corner). Can anyone please help me to sort out this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

You could include the logo(s) as part of the `\title`. However, titles carry to different areas of a PDF, specifically the PDF properties. So, we supply the title twice using `\texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdf>}`. `<tex>` contains all of the "messy logo placement", while `<pdf>` contains a clean title - `Quadratic Function` in this case.

[image]

```
\title{%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]
          {\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}% Left logo
      }\hfill
      \makebox[0pt]{Quadratic Function}%
      \hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]
          {\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-b}}% Right logo
      }%
    }%
  }
  {Quadratic Function}} % Poster title
```

If you need only one logo, just remove the `\includegraphics[..]{...}` construction.